# Remove a circle from Android Google Maps API v2 without clearing map

Tags: android, geometry, android-maps-v2

I am drawing a circle on my map like this:

```
CircleOptions circle=new CircleOptions();
circle.center(centre);
circle.strokeColor(0xFFFFA420);
circle.strokeWidth(2f);
circle.fillColor(0x11FFA420);
circle.radius(radius);
myMap.addCircle(circle);
```

To remove this circle, I am calling `myMap.clear()`, which removes all items added to the map.
The question is how to remove this circle without removing all others items on the map?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try calling [`remove()` on the `Circle` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle#remove%28%29) that you get back from `addCircle()`.
For Example

```
Circle mapCircle;
mapCircle = mapView.addCircle(circleOption);
```

Now when you want to remove 
Call this method

```
if(mapCircle!=null){
  mapCircle.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Code could be useful.

```
drawnCircle = map.addCircle(circle);
drawnCircle.remove();
```

Comment: adding a null check on drawCircle will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, you can use :  circle.visible(false)