# Draw a Circle of a fixed radius that can be drag-able?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I want to create a cricle on the Google Map that can be draggable from the user .But the radius of the the cirlce will be static.So any idea how can we do this.

This is how i am creating a **Circle**

```
Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(Latitude, longitude)).radius(100)
                .strokeColor(Color.RED));
```

Please suggest me what i have to do so that the circle can be draggable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [detect touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map) and after that add/remove the same circle (removing is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480997/remove-a-circle-from-android-google-maps-api-v2-without-clearing-map)). It might have some performance issues if You're going to react to every event.